# Swift mac app, run terminal command without knowing the path (so it looks in every path in $PATH)?

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, swift2, swift4

I'm trying to run terminal commands from my swift mac app, i want the users to enter any command like they would in the terminal without having to specify the real path. Is there a way to run a command and make it look in every path that's specified in the $PATH variable?

I can run commands when I specify the path but I need it to auto-find the binary from any path in the systems $PATH variable

```
    let path = "/usr/bin/killall"
    let arguments = ["Dock"]
    let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
    task.waitUntilExit()
```

In the future I would like to read .sh files and run every line in it, so for long scripts not all binaries will be in the default path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute the command via [`env`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/env.1.html):

```
env utility argument ...
```

Example:

```
let path = "/usr/bin/env"
let arguments = ["ls", "-l", "/"]
let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
task.waitUntilExit()
```

`env` locates the given utility using the `$PATH` variable and
then executes it with the given arguments. It has additional
options to specify a different search path and additional
environment variables.

(This is not a feature of Swift but of macOS and many other operating systems.)

When started from the Finder (double-click) the `PATH` may be different
from the `PATH` in your shell environment. If necessary, you can add
additional directories:

```
var env = task.environment ?? [:]
if let path = env["PATH"] {
    env["PATH"] = "/usr/local/bin:" + path
} else {
    env["PATH"] = "/usr/local/bin"
}
task.environment = env
```

---

[`execlp`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/exec.3.html) and friends also locate the executable using `$PATH` but offer only the "raw" C interface.

Comment: hmm, does not seem to work for cowsay & fortune :s, output : env: cowsay: No such file or directory

Comment: @Steven.B: What is "cowsay" and where is it located?

Comment: It seems to be in /usr/local/bin/cowsay , this is my output if I echo my $PATH => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin. the first path should contain the binary :s

Comment: @Steven.B: Does `env cowsay` work on the command line? What is the output of `type cowsay` and `file /usr/local/bin/cowsay` ?

Comment: "env cowsay" seems to work, output for "type cowsay" is "cowsay is hashed (/usr/local/bin/cowsay)
" when i run file /usr/local/bin/cowsay" I get "/usr/local/bin/cowsay: a /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ script text executable, ASCII text"

Comment: I have to add this was installed via brew package manager but i need the app to work with every command that works in the terminal,  Big thanks already :)

Comment: @Steven.B: The problem is probably that the Xcode application uses a different PATH variable and not the one from *your* shell. Try to execute the compiled binary on the command line and not within Xcode.

Comment: wow, running the .app with "open -a /xxxxxx/appname.app " seems to put show the expected output, however doubleclicking the .app does not seem to work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132594/discussion-between-martin-r-and-steven-b).