# execute shell internal commands from swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to execute shell commands from swift program. below is my program

```
func executeCommand(command: String, args: [String]) -> String {
    let task = Process()

    task.launchPath = command
    task.arguments = args

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String

    return output

}
```

When I use the path as /bin and try to execute ls command it works and prints the output. but when i try to run

```
executeCommand(command: "export DEVELOPER_DIR=\"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/\"", args: [""])
```

it is not working. I tried to find the location of export but terminal says it is inbuilt. How do i execute the export DEVELOPER_DIR from my swift program?

Comment: "export VARIABLE=value" is a shell built-in, and `Process` does not use the shell. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/41525955/1187415 how you can modify the environment before launching the process.

Comment: Or are you trying to modify the environment of your *current shell* from a launched process? That is not possible.

Comment: I am trying to write a swift program that iterates over multiple crash files and symbolicates. I get the developer_dir error when executing symbolicatecrash command. so wanted to executed the export command