# How to run scripts just as if user was using the terminal in cocoa app?

Tags: swift, xcode, bash, macos

I am new to macos development.

I am attempting to create a simple macos app in swift that uses a bash script to check if the user has Tor installed.

The following code is my view controller:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet var spinner: NSProgressIndicator!

    dynamic var isRunning = false
    var outputPipe:Pipe!
    var buildTask:Process!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        checkIfTorIsInstalled()

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    func checkIfTorIsInstalled() {

        spinner.startAnimation(self)
        runScript()

    }

    func runScript() {

        isRunning = true
        let taskQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background)

        taskQueue.async {

            //1.
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CheckForTor", ofType: "command") else {
                print("Unable to locate CheckForTor.command")
                return
            }

            //2.
            self.buildTask = Process()
            self.buildTask.launchPath = path

            //3.
            self.buildTask.terminationHandler = {

                task in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.spinner.alphaValue = 0
                    self.spinner.stopAnimation(self)
                    self.isRunning = false
                })

            }

            self.captureStandardOutputAndRouteToTextView(self.buildTask)

            //4.
            self.buildTask.launch()

            //5.
            self.buildTask.waitUntilExit()

        }

    }

    func captureStandardOutputAndRouteToTextView(_ task:Process) {

        //1.
        outputPipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = outputPipe
        task.standardError = outputPipe

        //2.
        outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()

        //3.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSFileHandleDataAvailable, object: outputPipe.fileHandleForReading, queue: nil) {
            notification in

            //4.
            let output = self.outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.availableData
            let outputString = String(data: output, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? ""

            //5.
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                print("outputString = \(outputString)")
            })

            //6.
            self.outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()

        }

    }

}
```

Then I have a script in my main bundle like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

#  CheckForTor.command
#  FullyNoded
#
#  Created by Peter on 03/10/19.
#  Copyright © 2019 Peter. All rights reserved.

tor --version
```

Running the app returns the following error:

```
/Users/peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FullyNoded-auhfxlayowyknmdyqlwszzkrnevb/Build/Products/Debug/FullyNoded.app/Contents/Resources/CheckForTor.command: line 9: tor: command not found
```

Yet when I open my terminal and run `tor --version` I get a valid response. How can I run scripts programmatically in a macos swift app and get the same functionality as if using the terminal directly on my mac?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41525955/1187415. – The problem is that applications started from the Finder have a different  PATH variable set in their environment, and that does not include locations like /usr/local/bin (where `tor` might be installed).

Comment: that did help, I changed the script to `/usr/local/bin/tor --version` but now get  `Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to click your Project, then click your projects target in XCode, then in "Capabilities" toggle off "App Sandbox"